# UEQ and sample size

Tags: research

for a client, we have already set up a survey measuring the UEQ. We are now wondering how many people we need each month to obtain reliable results that are stable over time and are not overly influenced by random variations or fluctuations. How can we calculate the appropriate sample size, even though the underlying measures are subjective?

Answer (score 1):

From UEQ's official site ([ueq-online.org](https://ueq-online.org)) you can download data analysis tool which has a calculator for calculating sample sizes. It has the following defaults:

[image]